# unable to get local issuer certificate WordPress 2018 PHP 7.2 - cacert.pem doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

So I've spent the last 2 days searching and reading almost every solution online for this, but have yet to fix the issue:

Running WordPress ver. 4.9.8. on latest version of XAMPP for Mac High Sierra (10.13.6)

Anytime a cURL or wp_remote_get() function is run, I am returned this error:

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I've have been through the solution of downloading the cacert.pem file and updating the php.ini file to include:

```
curl.cainfo="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/curl/cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/curl/cacert.pem"
```

I've also tried placing these in a number of different directories as well as including the default .crt file:

```
openssl.cafile="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

Restarted Apache and all every time I change the file, etc.

I've also checked file / folder permissions.

In addition to this not working on the localhost environment, I get the same error on my live (https) secure site. After contacting my hosting provider, they say all cURL operations on working and can't seem to find the error.

The only way I've been able to resolve the issue is by setting:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
```

As for other plugins running wp_remote_get, the only option is to set a filter for:

```
verifyssl => false
```

Has anyone else been experiencing this issue on either local or live sites using WordPress?

Does anyone have a solid solution?

I believe I've viewed every article and video on the entire interwebs looking for an answer...

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: How old is your `cacert.pem` file?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/2191572 ? Maybe you're changing the wrong php.ini file

Comment: You can `echo '<pre>';print_r(ini_get_all());` to verify that the setting is in effect.